# Retrieve/see saved password in toad 13 version

Tags: oracle, passwords, toad

I want to retrieve/see the saved password for a connection in Toad for oracle 13version.

I am aware that password can be seen by creating a DB link -> Show SQL. But this trick is working only till Toad 12 version. Can someone please help with a trick to see the password in Toad 13 version?

Comment: This question should perhaps be asked on superuser; just because coders use Toad doesn't mean that a Q like "how can I recover a password Toad has saved" is a good fit for a site about programming questions. Is there a password field full of ****** somewhere? You could try softwares intended to turn that off, like BulletsPassView though be aware some more secure programs don't put the actual password they've stored into the box, they put a random/alternative string of the same length, so revealing it doesn't help